# Create a pyTorch testing Dataset (without labels)

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have created a pyTorch dataset for my training data which consists of features and a label to be able to utilize the pyTorch DataLoader using [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) tutorial. This works well for my training data, but I get an error (`KeyError: "['label'] not found in axis"`) when loading the testing csv file, which is identical other than there being no "label" column.

If it helps, the intended input csv file is MNIST data in csv file which has 28*28 feature columns.

```
import torch

class mnist(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        self.train = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.train_x = self.train.drop("label", axis=1)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.train)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()
        if isinstance(idx, list):
            idx_len = len(idx)
        else:
            idx_len = 1
        
        X = np.asarray(self.train_x.iloc[idx], dtype=np.float32)
        X = np.reshape(X, (1,28,28))
        y = np.asarray(self.train.iloc[idx]['label'])
        
        sample = {'X': X, 'y':y}
        
        return torch.from_numpy(sample['X']), torch.from_numpy(sample['y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use both data with this:

```
import torch

class mnist(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        self.train = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

        self.training = "label" in self.train.columns
        self.train_x = self.train if not self.training else self.train.drop("label", axis=1)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.train)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        ...
        
        X = np.asarray(self.train_x.iloc[idx], dtype=np.float32)
        X = np.reshape(X, (1,28,28))
        if not self.training:
            return torch.from_numpy(X])

        y = np.asarray(self.train.iloc[idx]['label'])

        sample = {'X': X, 'y':y}
        return torch.from_numpy(sample['X']), torch.from_numpy(sample['y'])
```

Answer (score 0):

here i have used cifar10 dataset from torchvision.datasets.
& I will ignore its labels

```
import torch
class IgnoreLabelDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, orig):
        self.orig = orig

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.orig[index][0]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.orig)

import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

cifar = dset.CIFAR10(root='data/', download=True,
                         transform=transforms.Compose([
                             transforms.Scale(32),
                             transforms.ToTensor(),
                             transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
                         ])
)

dataset_with_no_labels = IgnoreLabelDataset(cifar)
```

So finally `dataset_with_no_labels` is my dataset object without labels